# VS2013 win 7 asp.net mvc, Jquery document ready is not getting called

Tags: jquery, asp.net, document-ready

I have created a simple ASP.NET MVC app in VS2013. Jquery document ready code is added in the following scripts section in Index.HTML to display simple alert message:

[image: scripts section]

After running the app from visual studio, noticed that message is not displayed.

Here is the Layout code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")    
</head>
<body>
    ...
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

Using Fiddler, noticed that jQuery is loaded in the browser:
[image: jquery in fiddler]

Not sure what happened, please help

Comment: Do you receive any client side JavaScript errors?

Comment: Any other suggestions?